# Large scale Objects and Area Lights

Tags: light, scene

I have a very basic scene (Box on a plane, area light on top) but it has a huge scale as I want it to be in real world coords.
My units are set to mm / metric.
My box has dimensions of 2m^3 and the plane has 15m^2.
The area light is a square with the size of 2m and is pointing perpendicular to the ground, it's position is right above the cube.

When I use the live-rendering mode in cycles, I need ludicrous values for the area light to actually see anything (>50000000).

What is the issue here? What is the thing with units in blender?

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include some screenshots of your render and render settings.

Comment: could you please upload this blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ? Can't yet reproduce the issue here.

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2530" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2530/)

Comment: Probably it is important to know that this has been tested on a windows 10 64-bit machine with a gtx 980 and a gtx 1080.

Comment: Nobody knows an answer? Or has an explanation for this? Is it a bug probably?